# Multiple HttpPost due to multiple submit buttons against same action

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a scenario where I required two submit buttons:

**CsHtml:**

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "Letter", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    @* Very big form *@

    if (ViewData["ShowButtons"]?.ToString() == "1")
    {
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100 me-5px" formaction="@nameof(LetterController.CreateSave)" title="@(Model.IsUpdateCase ? "Update letter" : "Save letter")">@(Model.IsUpdateCase ? "Update" : "Save")</button>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default w-100" formaction="@nameof(LetterController.CreateSubmit)" title="@(Model.IsUpdateCase ? "Update letter & submit" : "Save letter & submit")">Submit</button>
    }    
}
```

**Controller:**

```cs
public class LetterController
{

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(long? letterId)
    {
        // Prepare model

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateSave(LetterModel model)
    {
        ModelState.Clear();

        LetterCustomValidation(model);

        model.ProposalDetails = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<LetterProposalDetailModel>>(model.ProposalDetailsStringify!)!;

        LetterCustomValidation(model, true);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return RedirectToAction("CreateSave", model);

        var result = await SaveLetter(model);

        if (result != null)
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        ViewData["CreateNotif"] = "Letter was not saved properly";
        return RedirectToAction("CreateSave", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateSubmit(LetterModel model)
    {
        ModelState.Clear();

        var validationResult = await letterValidator.ValidateAsync(model);

        if (!validationResult.IsValid)
        {
            validationResult.AddToModelState(ModelState);

            return RedirectToAction("CreateSubmit", model);
        }

        LetterCustomValidation(model);       

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return RedirectToAction("CreateSubmit", model);

        var result = await SaveLetter(model);

        if (result == null)
        {
            ViewData["UpdateNotif"] = "Letter was not saved properly";
            return RedirectToAction("Create", model);
        }

        var actionResult = await service.ActionAsync(result.Id, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "ActionType", 0 }, { "ActionTakenBy", currentUser.Id } }, new CancellationToken());

        if (actionResult)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewData["ActionNotif"] = "Letter was not submitted properly";
        return RedirectToAction("CreateSubmit", model);
    }
}

private void LetterCustomValidation(LetterModel model, bool skipToSpecial = false)
{
    var letterTypeHelper = new[] { 1, 2 };

    if (skipToSpecial)
    {
        if (letterTypeHelper.Contains(model.LetterTypeId) && !model.ProposalDetails.Any())
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(model.ProposalDetails), "Please enter a valid value(s)");
        }

        return;
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.Subject))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(model.Subject), "Please provide appropriate subject before submitting.");
    }

    if (model.OverrideLetter && model.OverriddenLetter == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(model.OverriddenLetter), "Please select a valid letter to override");
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.CompanyName))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(model.CompanyName), "Please select a valid company");
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.BrandName))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(model.BrandName), "Please select a valid brand");
    }
    
    // Many more
}
```

Please note that I left the submit action blank in the form on purpose. I land in the correct Post action when I press the two submit buttons.

Now, the issue:

Whenever I get a validation error in my model through my custom validation schemes (full custom + FluentValidation), I tend to add the errors to the `ModelState`. By default, we use to do a `return View(model);`. Now, I can't do that since my actions have a different name and I'm using a `return RedirectToAction("Either-Post-Methods", model);` instead.

Whenever I do a `RedirectToAction`, I either land on a 405 Error page or a blank page with no values from my model but rather a null-like model. Is there something elementary wrong with my approach?

Comment: There _is_ no `Index()` action method though? Do you mean "Create"?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yeah... there is an index that shows a list. All that is working. This `Create` action, and it's two Posts that are causing issues. If creation is successful, I redirect to the Index

Comment: As far as I know, the redirecttoAction will let the client redirect to the another action. This will be a get method, so the server will return the 405 error status.  Besides, you code always call the same action CreateSave. I think it will loop always.